# Getting parameter error in SQL Server 2000 when trying to connect to DB

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, windows-server-2003

[Screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLqj2.png)

Any idea why this keeps happening? The Username is correct (using Mixed Mode), and the password is correct as well.

SQL services are running.

This is on Windows Server 2003 btw.

Wanted to connect the new installation with the newly created DB.

Comment: It looks like sql server 2000, are you really installing this in 2024? Or has this question been magically transported itself through time? It looks like your server is running on named pipes or instance, while you're trying to connect through localhost without instance name. Why not use the same host as the one you have blurred out?

Comment: When you asked your question, you were told *"Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question (and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)), and [format them appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)."* Please follow the instructions when posting your questions, as otherwise you are likely to receive down and/or close votes; meaning your question is far less likely to be answered.

Comment: Have you considered using a *modern* environment? Both those pieces of software ran *entirely* out of support a decade or more ago. You are, in truth, going to likely find very few who recall specifics of such an *old* version, and even less than have access to one that could test.

Comment: You should connect using `.\LYRISLM` for a named instance on the same machine.

Comment: Anywhere that's prompting for a username and password to connect to SQL Server will be expecting SQL Login credentials, i.e.: you won't be able to enter credentials for a Windows account here.